# Multiple Screen Support - Android Studio?

Tags: android, layout, screen

I know that i have to put this code in manifest

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

also i created different layout sizes and dimens:

```
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

Here is the confusion, the phone will pick automatically the screen size but there are different phone with screen sizes that pick same layout size. Let say layout-normal can take starting galaxy one and S up to galaxy 6 which have different screen size. In layout-normal is only one file but it will not fit all phones which takes layout-normal. 
How to design and fix that layout that fixes every screen in layout-normal?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have checked many time this link, not really helpful.